# unable to load my site after exporting into cpanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

this is my cpanel img. unable to load my site.after inspect the elements also iam unable to load it.I have a domain on cpanel that i have been using for the past three weeks. However today I logged in to the File Manager and deleted the WordPress files that were previously there (did not remove cgi-bin). I then replaced these files with another instance of the WordPress site

Answer (score 0):

1. First get a single page to load (or skip to 2).
2. Copy everything over as a backup and remove that domain, then re-add it.
3. I recommend using softaculous wordpress for managing word press instances, so use their tool to create a new site.
4. Finally, copy your theme into the default theme folder and you should be set.